# Decode this Hotel RFID card lock data checksum

Tags: checksum

I have hexadecimal data from first 5 blocks of T5557 125KHz RFID card for Chinese made hotel room door lock. The 5th block appear to be some kind of checksum which I like to know how it is derived.

Below are 12 different samples of the data. Rows 1 to 5 in the tables represent block 1 to 5 of T5557 125 KHz RFID card.

```
(1)

| Block  |  Data     |
|--------|-----------|
|Block 1 |C9 09 3C F1|
|Block 2 |00 01 01 01|
|Block 3 |0C 61 D8 BB|
|Block 4 |00 D8 D3 00|
|Block 5 |70 9E 94 3F|

(2)
| Block  |  Data     |
|--------|-----------|
|Block 1 |C9 09 44 F1|
|Block 2 |00 01 01 01|
|Block 3 |0C 65 D8 C3|
|Block 4 |00 D8 D3 00|
|Block 5 |07 E4 C1 DA|

(3)
| Block  |  Data     |
|--------|-----------|
|Block 1 |C9 09 4C F1|
|Block 2 |00 01 01 01|
|Block 3 |0F 67 D8 CB|
|Block 4 |00 D8 D3 00|
|Block 5 |68 20 81 85|

(4)
| Block  |  Data     |
|--------|-----------|
|Block 1 |C9 09 4C F1|
|Block 2 |00 01 01 01|
|Block 3 |08 68 D8 CB|
|Block 4 |00 D8 D3 00|
|Block 5 |AA 0A 1E 0A|
    
(5)
| Block  |  Data     |
|--------|-----------|
|Block 1 |C9 09 4C 31|
|Block 2 |00 01 01 01|
|Block 3 |09 6A D8 CB|
|Block 4 |40 D8 D3 00|
|Block 5 |02 37 8C 3A|

(6)
| Block  |  Data     |
|--------|-----------|
|Block 1 |C9 09 4C 71|
|Block 2 |00 01 01 01|
|Block 3 |0A 6C D8 CB|
|Block 4 |80 D8 D3 00|
|Block 5 |D0 D2 13 AA|

(7)
| Block  |  Data     |
|--------|-----------|
|Block 1 |C9 09 4C F1|
|Block 2 |00 01 01 01|
|Block 3 |10 69 D6 CB|
|Block 4 |00 D6 D3 00|
|Block 5 |67 05 08 85|

(8)
| Block  |  Data     |
|--------|-----------|
|Block 1 |C9 09 4C F1|
|Block 2 |00 01 01 01|
|Block 3 |11 6B D7 CB|
|Block 4 |00 D7 D3 00|
|Block 5 |4A ED 23 40|

(9)
| Block  |  Data     |
|--------|-----------|
|Block 1 |C9 09 4C F1|
|Block 2 |00 01 01 01|
|Block 3 |12 6D D8 CB|
|Block 4 |00 D8 D3 00|
|Block 5 |06 79 70 76|

(10)
| Block  |  Data     |
|--------|-----------|
|Block 1 |C9 09 4C F1|
|Block 2 |00 01 01 01|
|Block 3 |13 6F B8 CB|
|Block 4 |00 B8 D3 00|
|Block 5 |85 40 F9 B9|

(11)
| Block  |  Data     |
|--------|-----------|
|Block 1 |C9 09 4C F1|
|Block 2 |00 01 01 01|
|Block 3 |14 61 CB CB|
|Block 4 |00 CB D3 00|
|Block 5 |A6 A0 06 D5|

(12)
| Block  |  Data     |
|--------|-----------|
|Block 1 |C9 09 4C F1|
|Block 2 |00 01 01 01|
|Block 3 |15 63 D8 CB|
|Block 4 |00 D8 D3 00|
|Block 5 |95 72 B6 E4|
```

Is anyone able to figure out how data in row 5 was derived?

Many thanks in advance.